# Batch exit if drive device not ready/unavailable

Tags: batch-file

I need to force a batch file to stop and exit the batch program (but not the command prompt) if selecting a drive/device fails because it is not ready/unavailable.

I've tried...

```
d: || exit /b
```

...and I also tried...

```
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 exit /b %errorlevel%
```

...after every line without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this :

```
if not exist d: exit/b
```

Comment: Depending on what type the drive actually is, this may cause cmd to throw a "cmd.exe - No Disk / There is no disk in the drive. Please insert a disk into drive \Device\<whatever>. Cancel / Try Again / Continue" dialog and block until the user responds to it.